# remote true not working in form in rails2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am using ruby 1.8.7. I just wrote a simple form that sends ajax request to certain action using remote true, but it isn't seem to be working!

I have included jquery1.6.3.js and rails.js. The form is simple and looks like this:

```
<% form_tag("/click_button", :remote => true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "something" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

The click_button method just renders the js

```
def click_button
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

The problem with is that when I click the button, there is no request to be seen in the console of the firebug, instead the page is being redirected to /click_button.erb and it gives an missing error template. Can anyone please help me with this?

**[Edited]**
The generated html code is like this:

```
<form remote="true" method="post" action="/data_management/add_configuration_data">
  <input id="something" type="text" name="something">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" name="commit">
</form>
```

Comment: jquery 1.6? that's pretty old! and is this ruby on rails or something like that? if yes, please tag the question accordingly. and please include the generated HTML code in your question

Comment: Rails 2? Didn't that use remote_form_for or something like that?

Comment: yes, it is ruby on rails. I changed the jquery to 1.8.2 but still its redirecting rather than sending ajax request. -see the edited section for generated html code

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the remote handler is not attached to the form. Double check that

1. the jQuery library is linked from the page and make sure the link works. Sometimes it's mispelled. Open the source and check it.
2. the rails.js file is linked from the page and the link works. Same as above.
3. Add the `csrf_meta_tag` tags in the page in the header section

   ```
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  <% form_remote_for :xyz, :url => {:controller => "controller-name", :action => "action-name"} do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag "something" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For rails 2.3.8 you have to use [`remote_form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002170)  OR [`form_remote_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002169) instead  `:remote => true`

```
<% remote_form_for("/click_button"e) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "something" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you are rite but remote_form_for uses prototype.js not jquery.js. It has old requests like Ajax.request. :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something like remote_true but it didn't seem to work so I found one way of solving this issue through [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery).