# Submitting a JQuery Dialog modal form on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I want to render a modal form in JQuery Dialog. I made use of the existing form created during generate Scaffold. Right now, I face some problems submitting the form through a dialog button rather than the html one.

The form below will be rendered in a JQuery Dialog upon clicking of a button. (Generated by Scaffold)

```
<%= form_for(@user, :remote=>true) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :account_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :account_type %>
  </div>
  <div id="submit-button" class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Right now, I wish to change the submit button to a JQuery function.
The following codes to a button in JQuery.

```
  <div id="submit-button" class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

This is the Jquery codes for the modal form.

```
   $( "#form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        resizable:false,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {
                    $("#form").submit();
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

So essentially it is to change it from

```
  <div id="submit-button" class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

to something like

```
  $("#form").submit();
```

I face some problems doing it, I figure it might be something to do with the referencing but I can't figure out how to change it.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In your actual HTML, what is the id of your form? With `$("#form")` you are specifying the id of the form to be `form`, but it is probably something like `edit_user`, so it should be something like `$("#edit_user")` or whatever the id of the form is.

Comment: this [should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery)

Comment: It worked. I did                 "Create an account": function() {
                        $("#new_user").submit();
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }