# Rails remote form submit not working

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax/js.  When I set :remote => true it still submits via html.

```
<%= form_for(@message), :remote => true, do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :Note_To_Doctor %>
  <%= f.text_field :note %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:physician_id, Physician.all, :id, :physician_name )%>
<%= f.button :send, :class => 'btn btn-info' %>

<% end %>
```

I could have sworn I've done it like this.  Do I need to create a create.js.erb and if so, what should go inside of it.  Also, what should I put inside the create action as a respond block?

controller:

```
 def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.save
      MessageMailer.paging(@message).deliver
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to messages_path, flash.notice = "Message was sent" }
         format.js { render "index" }
       end
    else
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    end
  end
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#messages").html("<%= escape_javascript render("messages") %>");
```

Comment: did you solve this problem? i have the same...

Answer (score 1):

Just replace form_for with,

```
<%= form_for(@message, :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I've tried that and the form submits the message and mails it out but I have to refresh the page to show the message sent.  Don't I need a create.js.erb with $("#messages").html("<%= escape_javascript render("messages") %>"); inside of it?  Also, what should my respond block in my controller action look like?

Comment: Added a respond block to the create action in the controller to respond to js, also created index.js.erb but no luck.  The partial for "messages" does not refresh on submit.

Comment: I would like to suggest to inspect java script console for this.

Comment: Javascript console comes up with no errors.  What should I be inspecting?

Comment: try putting alert messages to index.js and see if it is getting rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `:remote=>true` is not working you should try this solution. [Submit form in rails 3 in an ajax way (with jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery)