# rails submit form w/o refresh, :remote => true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I'm trying to submit a form in rails without refreshing the page afterwards. I've been looking around online, but it seems that adding :remote => true doesn't seem to change my form the way I thought it would. Right now I have each question having a number of answers, and each one is connected to a radio button, but I've hidden the radio button so clicking on the label itself submits the form. Does the page refresh as a result of the radio button form submission? I'm really not sure, and would appreciate any help at this point...

```
<%= form_for(uanswer, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <% answers.each_with_index do |answer, i| %>
    <% unless answered_flag %>
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id, :class => "radio hide", 
            :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :answer_id, answer.answer, :class => "answer",
        :value => answer.id %>
<% end %>
```

The generated HTML form looks more or less like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/uanswers" class="new_uanswer" 
 data-remote="true" id="new_uanswer" method="post"><div  
 style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input 
 name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token"
 type="hidden" value="PY5ACVmrvDnt/iYF8RK6O7tDKAn2G2dFdLeBNZw5MJ4="></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Whatever gets rendered after the form is submitted depends on what the action that the form is posted to decides to render. As you haven't actually posted that controller action in your question I can't provide a proper answer other than to suggest you try `render :nothing => true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The remote=>true isn't doing anything for you right now as you are bypassing rails with the this.form.submit(). You need to submit the form asynchronously. See [Submit form in rails 3 in an ajax way (with jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery) for a solution to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `this.form.submit()` to `$(this).closest('form').submit()` worked for me. I use the "onchange" method instead on "onclick" for my form fields though.