# Display 'show' action in partial within the 'index' action's view - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a property search page (:controller => 'properties', :action => 'index') that consists of a right sidebar that has a search form which displays the search results below the form. When the user clicks on a property in the right sidebar I want to display the details of that property in the main area of the index page on the left.

Right sidebar is a partial called properties/_property.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag properties_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<%= text_field_tag 'location', (params[:location]) %>
<%= select_tag(:max, options_for_select([['No Max', ""], ['$100,000', 100000], ['$200,000', 200000], etc %>
more search fields for baths beds etc
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<% @properties.each do |property| %>
<%= link_to([property.Address,property.City].join(", "), {:action => 'show', :id => property.id}) %>
<li><strong><%= number_to_currency(property.Price, :precision => 0) %></strong></li>
etc etc
<% end %>
```

The only way I know how to show the property details is with the 'show' action, but that takes the user to a new page, for example localhost:3000/properties/1865. I've made the 'show' view with the same layout as the 'index' view and have made the right sidebar a partial (properties/_property.html.erb) which appears on both 'show' and 'index' so when the user clicks on a property in the right sidebar and goes to localhost:3000/properties/1865 the property details are displayed correctly in the main area and the right sidebar is on the right.

But because localhost:3000/properties/1865 is a different page than localhost:3000/properties/index the search form in the right sidebar has forgotten it's parameters which means the list of search results in the right sidebar has changed back to the default list of all properties.

How can I display the 'show' action within a partial on the index page so the user's search parameters are remembered by the form in the right sidebar? Or if I have to go to the 'show' page how can I make the right sidebar stay exactly as it is?

Any ideas greatly appreciated, just a suggestion in the right direction would be good, have spent all day trying to figure it out and have got nowhere, thanks

Comment: have tried implementing answer below but cant get anything to work, further question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425641/show-action-in-partial-wont-display-in-index-view-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have made the show view with the same layout as the index view and
>   have made the right sidebar a partial (properties/_property.html.erb)
>   which appears on both show and index.

Yes but this will only get you a similar layout for both the pages. You want the list to persist between different requests.

You basically have two options. use session to remember the list which I wont recommend.

Other is you use form :remote => true or ajax and update the page partially.

**EDIT:**

What version of rails you are using? Do u have jquery loaded in your application?

Follow this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery).

You might have to change your show action a bit.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render :partial => 'property_details' ,:layout => false}
  format.html 
end
```

Create a partial for property details and just put body content here.

And link will look like

```
<%= link_to "link name", {:action => :show, :id => item_id}, :remote => true ,:html => {:class => 'links_product'} %>
```

Also to update the view you may use(make sure you have rails.js in your page):

```
$(document).ready(
     function(){
          $("a.links_product").bind("ajax:success",
                   function(evt, data, status, xhr){                           
                        $("#response").html(data); // in case data is html. (_*.html.erb)
           }).bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error){
                   console.log('server error' + error );
           });
});
```

Have a div with id `response` or any valid id. Done!

Comment: thanks, rails 3.2.11 with jquery loaded. I spent a few hours trying ajax but couldn't figure out how to display the show in the index action because even with a partial it's still within the index action so I couldn't get the controller part right as I was still trying to mix 2 actions. Is your code above for the index action in the properties_controller?

Comment: well it depends. I would suggest to update the property panel(show action) ajaxically. So when you click on the link on the right panel. You get only property details and not full page.

Comment: so the link to click in the right panel would be this?: <%= link_to([property.Address,property.City].join(", "), {:action => 'show', :id => property.id, :remote => true}) %> Do I then have to make a show.js.erb page? How do I put that in a partial? Maybe the partial is _show.js.erb? Sorry for being so clueless

Comment: Put `:remote => true` as 3rd argument. you can use _show.html.erb or _product_detail.html.erb or even abc.js.erb. Be sure to render that partial in case of ajax requests. i.e. inside `format.js` block

Comment: right I get it now, I wasn't rendering the partial in the format.js block of the show action, thanks very much for your help, much appreciated

Comment: I've got the show action's partial _property_details.html.erb within the index page but when I try to load the index page for the first time there's an error: undefined method `Address' for nil:NilClass because there is no (params[:id]) for the show action as stated in the properties_controller: @property = Property.find(params[:id]). I've tried hard coding an id into @property just to test it but @property always comes back as nil