# Show action in partial won't display in index view - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have my show action within a partial called properties/_property_details.html.erb that I'm trying to display with ajax within the index action's view.

properties/index.html.erb:

```
<div id="showdiv">
    <%= render :partial => 'property_details' %>
  </div>
```

properties/_property_details.html.erb:

```
<div id="response">
<h3>
<%= [@property.Address,@property.City,"FL"].join(", ") %> <%= @property.Zip %></h3> 
etc etc     </div>
```

However, when I try to load the index page the @property variable of the show action is nil so I get an

```
undefined method `Address' for nil:NilClass
```

presumably because there is no (params[:id]) for the show action as required in the properties_controller:

```
def show
@property = Property.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render :partial => 'property_details' ,:layout => false}
  format.html
end

end
```

But if that's the case then I should be able to hard code a value for @property in the show action just to test this but the following code still gives the same undefined method for nilclass error when I try to load the index page containing the partial:

```
def show
  @property = Property.find(1)

respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render :partial => 'property_details' ,:layout => false}
  format.html
end

end
```

Why is @property coming back as nil? I opened the rails console and did p = Property.find(1) and got a property returned so for some reason the partial isn't listening to the show action in the controller when it's within my index page.

The partial works fine when it's within the properties/show.html.erb like this:

```
<div class="twothirds">
<%= render :partial => 'property_details' %>
</div>
<div class="onethird">
<%= render :partial => 'property' %>
</div>
```

So it's only when I'm trying to put the partial within my index page that it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `@property.Address` correct? It is not `@property.address`?

Comment: yes that's correct, the _property_details.html.erb partial works fine when I put it within the properties/show.html.erb file

Comment: railsy, @murifoX is correct that your naming convention appears to be incorrect -- i've never seen related model be referred to in uppercase.

Comment: I inherited the column names from a wordpress database that I'm linking to and data gets imported everyday from that db so it's easier to keep them as they are

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at Ajax so I was mistakenly including the partial for the show action in the index action before the user had clicked on a link to display the show action. So I've replaced the partial in the index action with just an empty div and I replace the empty div with the partial through ajax only when the user clicks on a property link to view a property through the show action.