# Jquery asynchronous form submission in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, asynchronous

I am trying to upload an image using asynchronous submission of form , this is my Rails HTML :

```
<%= form_for(:image, :url => {:controller=> 'questions',:action => 'upload_Qimage'}, :html => {:id=>'qimage_upload'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :image, :onchange => " return uploadImage() ; "  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id , :value => Digest::MD5.hexdigest((current_user.id + Time.now.to_i).to_s )[0,7] %>
<% end %>
```

This is my js function uploadImage() :

```
function uploadImage ()
    {
       $('#qimage_upload').submit() ; 
    $('#qimage_upload').submit( function() {  
                    return false ;   
       }
```

Ignore the ajax code inside the submit function , I cannot get the second alert even after commenting it out . I have been working on this all day now and can't figure out what's wrong with it .

**UPDATE** : Please note the update in the code above , using a simple submit() with no callback works but it does not serve my purpose as it tries to render a view for the action . Is this a jQuery version issue ?

**Second update**

This is what my controller action looks like :

```
def upload_Qimage

       @image = Image.new(params[:image])
       @image.save

   end
```

No matter what I try with the jQuery and html, it still tries to render a view. The file is saved with the current updated js but it still tries to render a view when I want it do nothing or rather just return some data (not a partial render, just data)

Comment: have you tried  :remote => true in form_for tag?

Comment: Yes , does not do anything . My issue is with alert in the submit function . It should trigger , regardless of what else is in there .

Comment: submit event will be called when you will submit the form. But in your form there is no submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn the difference between `.submit()` and `.submit(handler)`: the first method submits the form whereas the second one just binds an event handler to the event. So an alert doesn't appear because you bind the event handler but do not actually submit the form. Try running `$('#qimage_upload').submit()` **after** binding a handler:

```
$('#qimage_upload').submit(function() {  
    alert(1);
    $.ajax({
        // blah-blah-blah
    });
    return false; 
}); 
$('#qimage_upload').submit();
```

Comment: Thanks , that makes things clear . But I was following the answer from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-a-ajax-way-with-jquery

Using a .submit() rails tries to render the view for the action . I want to silently upload the image asynchronously. How do I do that ?

Comment: Hey , mentioning submit afterwards does not actually call the submit because of the binder , the only option seems to be writing an ajax request for uploading the image file which is a messy task . Calling the submit before the binder makes the binder useless (check my second update)

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger the alert no matter what happened with the AJAX?

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR
>
> `jqXHR.always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown) { });`

This will trigger in any case, either success of failure of the AJAX call.

You are also missing to capture the event and stop it from further execution. Take a look at the [events](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (this is also valid for vanilla JavaSCript).

```
$('#qimage_upload').submit() ; //This triggers and submitts the form  
$('#qimage_upload').submit( function() {  //therefore, you will never reach this when the new page has been loaded
    ... }
```

Therefore, stop the event from happening

```
$('#qimage_upload').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

....

return false;
});
```

I know that `return false` can be enough, but this is the proper way to handle it.

Comment: Please take a note of the update above , alert was being used for debugging . It seems the problem is with describing a callback function with submit . Please advise on the same .

Comment: I did not make it clear , I used the first submit just now as part of debugging . The original code wouldn't have two submits . Just the second one with a callback . I want the submit with a callback to work . But currently only the submit without callback is working . I am not using them together , but commenting out one when using the other.

Comment: I actually need to stop the new page from rendering after the submit, just load the image asynchronously and that's it .