# jquery hide on rails form submit button click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following form in my rails view:

```
<%= form_for :search do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :search_by_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :by_name  %>
      <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

In jQuery, I can do something like this:

```
        $("h1").click(function(){
            $("h1").hide();
        });
```

That would cause all `h1` tags to become invisible upon clicking an `h1` tag. How can I instead cause my entire form to become invisible by clicking on the "submit" button for my form above?

## EDIT

Perhaps the issue is a little bigger than I'm thinking. When I do this per the answer below:

```
 $("form").submit(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

The form becomes invisible, but then the page is immediately reloaded and the form is visible again. It stays invisible for a split second before reloading the page. Is there a way to carry that affect over from page to page, or to display the form results without reloading the page?

## Edit 2

Problem solved. I wrapped the form in a div class and passed that ID into the hide function as mentioned in the comments below, and that seems to work. I don't understand why the page was just realoading and displaying the form when passing in `form`, but it doesn't have that effect when passing in a `id`. But, problem solved.

Comment: What's the id of the form? Just use that in your hide function.

Comment: You want to lear about ajax, read something about remote forms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery

Comment: Ajax, time to bite the bullet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $("form").submit(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that Ajax is what you want (like @arieljuod said) but if you just wanted to hide the form without passing data to the server you could have prevented the event.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
})
```