# How to pass error message without closing modal window for login form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I having login form which contains username and password. if it's not present it will show the error message like "Invalid username and password".
But when i click submit button without giving username and password. it won't show the error message. instead of that automatically modal window is closed. After that again i will click modal window it shows the error message..

login.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <i class='fa fa-angle-up'></i>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= bootstrap_flash %>
        <div id="loginbox">      
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>      
            <%= form_for @user_session, html: { class: 'class="form-vertical" form' } do |form| %>
              <%= form.text_field :username,    :placeholder => "User Name", class: 'input-xxlarge' %><br><br>
              <%= form.password_field :password,:placeholder => "Password",  class: 'input-xxlarge' %><br><br>
              <%= button_tag( 'Sign In', type: 'submit', class: 'btn-mini btn-warning font' )%>
            <% end %>             
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <%= link_to "Forgot Password?",new_password_reset_path, :class => "forgot-password pasword" %>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

User_session controller

```
def create
        @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
        if @user_session.save
            @user = User.find_by_username(@user_session.username)
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            if params[:remember_me]
                cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = @user.auth_token
            else
                cookies[:auth_token] = @user.auth_token  
            end
          flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."

          case current_user.role_name
          when 'Admin'
            redirect_to dashboard_path
          when 'Teacher'
            redirect_to conversations_path
          when 'Student'
            redirect_to conversations_path
          when 'Employee'
            redirect_to conversations_path
          when 'Guardian'
            redirect_to conversations_path
          else
            redirect_to schools_path
          end        
        else
            flash[:error] = "Invalid Username or Password"
            redirect_to login_path
        end 
    end
```

Without reload the modal window shows the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Submit the form in ajax with remote: true in form

```
<%= form_for @user_session, html: { class: 'class="form-vertical" form' }, remote: true do |form| %>
<% end %>
```

In controller

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end
end
```

Edit:

Check with the stream [Submit form in rails 3 in an ajax way (with jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery)