# How do I render & show an error on the current view/partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a form partial that I want to show the error messages on the partial without redirecting elsewhere.

How do I do that?

This is my `PostsController#Create`

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Report was successfully sent to our editors for review.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the simple_form partial that the user is on, that I want to show the error messages either inline on the right field or even just at the top of the form without redirecting.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %> 
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input_field :parent_id, as: :hidden %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <% if can? :manage, @post %>
                    <label for="status">
                        Status
                            </label>
                            <%= f.input_field :status, label: "Status", collection: Post.statuses.keys, selected: :unconfirmed %>
                    <% end %>           

                        <% if can? :manage, @post %>
                <label for="title">
                    Title
                            </label>
                        <%= f.input_field :title, placeholder: "Enter Title"  %>
                            <span id="wordCountTitle">0</span> words<br/>
                            <span class="help-block">A block of help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend beyond one line.</span>            
                        <% end %>
                            <div class="report-field">
                    <label for="report">
                        Report
                                </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-file-text"></span>
                        </span>
                                    <%= f.input_field :body, id: "body-field", placeholder: "Provide all the facts of what happened, who did it, and where it happened.", class: "form-control", rows: "4" %><br />
                                </div>
                                <span class="help-block">Please avoid speculation.</span>                                           
                                <span id="wordCountBody">0</span> / 150 words
                            </div>
                            <br/>

                <label for="name">
                    Check if you are an eye witness:
                            </label>
                            <%= f.input_field :has_eyewitness, boolean_style: :inline %>
                            <br/>

                            <div>
                            <label for="photoFileUpload">Upload Images:</label>
                                <%= f.input_field :photo %>
                            <p class="help-block">Allowed: png, gif, jpg/jpeg</p>
                          </div>

                            <div>
                            <label for="FileUpload">Upload Documents, Video, or Audio:</label>
                                <%= f.input_field :file %>
                            <p class="help-block">Allowed: pdf, doc, xls, mp4, m4v, mp3, wav.</p>
                          </div>
        </div>

        <% if can? :manage, @post %>
                <%= f.input :youtube_embed_code %> <br />
                <%= f.input :soundcloud_embed_code %> <br />
            <% end %>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary pull-left" %>
    </div>          
    </div> <!-- //row -->
<% end %>
```

Right now, whenever there is an error with the creation, it renders the `posts/new.html.erb` view (per the controller.

Comment: `render :new` doesn't **redirect** to new action, it just renders `new` view. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nitish What I am trying to do is whenever a user tries to complete this form that validates my validations (e.g. password too short, blank title, etc.) it should show them the error messages right there without sending them to another page and showing them an error on that new page. In other words, I want the server-side validation to run but the filled out form to be shown along with the errors so the user can fix it and successfully submit the form.

Comment: I have never used simple_form. But usually I use [this](https://gist.github.com/nitishsp/b67fd6253da97cc7bfba) to display validation errors.

Comment: @Nitish Will that show on the form without doing a full page refresh?

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh at all, either you will have to use [ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery) or a gem like [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)