# Rails form submission without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

Using the Play framework I can create a form that the user can fill out and submit, bringing up a javascript confirmation popup that disappears after a second, and doesn't refresh the page. That is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sErFQiifHKI

However, I can't seem to replicate this in Rails. I've tried using

```
<%= form_tag "/", :autocomplete => :off, :name => 'sentMessage', :remote => 'true', :id => 'contactForm', :authenticity_token => true, :method => 'post' do %>
```

and in routes.rb

```
post '/' => 'home#submit_contact'
```

finally, in home_controller.rb

```
def submit_contact
    redirect_to '#contact'
end
```

and it will bring up the javascript confirmation popup, but it will also refresh the page which is not what I want! Is there a way to replicate what is shown in the video in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is a remote form your action should also respond back with the js / json response,  rather than redirecting to  new action

You can add these lines in your controller action and define the corresponding js template (submit_contact.js.erb file)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

In this js template you can write your JavaScript code.

Comment: The javascript code is located in form.js. If I use: `def submit_contact

  respond_to do |form|

      form.js { render :js => "processForm(contactForm);" }
             end
         end`, it gives me the error "ActionController::UnknownFormat"

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default action and make an asynchronous request.

If you can use jQuery, something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723501/2438633) should work. Otherwise, it shouldn't be too hard to adjust it for pure js.