# Send data to controller through modal in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in RoR and I'm stuck in this situation for a time now. I'm using a bootstrap modal with a table showing the users from database, and besides each a rage field. Need to send to controller the `user_id` and the value of the range.
Something like this:

```
{0 {user_id1 : range_value1}, 1 {user_id2 : range_value2}}
```

Partial modal:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
   <h3 id="modalLabel">Distribuir Estudos</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Integrante</th>
        <th>Papel</th>
        <th>Distribuição</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @users_protocols.each do |user_protocol| %>
        <tr>
          <td hidden><%= hidden_field :user_id, value: user_protocol.id %></td>
          <td><%= user_protocol.user.username %></td>
          <td><%= user_protocol.role.name %></td>
            <td>
              &nbsp;
              <span class="range-content">
                <input type="range" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="100"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>100</span>
              </span>
              <span>%</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
  <%= link_to distribute_protocol_path, method: :put, :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'btnDistribute' do %>
      Distribuir
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Application.js

```
$('#btnDistribute').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        #Recover data from modal and send to controller
});
```

Controller:

```
def distribute_studies
    @users_protocols = Protocol.find(params[:id]).users_protocols.includes(:user).each do |user_protocol|
      puts user_protocol.id
      puts user_protocol.role.name
      puts user_protocol.user.username
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :back }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js   { render :layout => false }
    end
  end

  def distribute
    #DO SOMETHING WITH DATA HERE

    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723334/submit-form-in-rails-3-in-an-ajax-way-with-jquery 
Idea being, create a rails form and form the `json` data on click. Or just get the individual field values using jquery with `id` attributes and populate json accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I've create and `json` object and in ajax call I'm passing through `data` this object. But I'm getting two answers from the controller, even using `e.preventDefault()`. Plus, I'm not being able to recover the `json`object in controller

Comment: When you are already getting data through Jquery, why add remote true to link ? just remove that and it should be fine. Also you might add a button instead.

Comment: That make sense, and it worked. But yet, I can't recover the data coming from ajax, somehow it's saying `undefined=""`

Comment: It depends on what you are returning from server back to browser. Have you created a separate view named `distribute_studies.js.erb` ? which lists what needs to be rendered ? Also do check what kind of request you get on server like if its `json` or `js`

Comment: I forgot to use `JSON.stringify(obj)`, now it's working as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I was of help :) Upvote my comments if they helped :)